# Which JDBC driver for SQL Server supports JRE6?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2012

Where I can find a JDBC driver for SQL Server that supports JRE6?

On the [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) there is no JDBC driver available for JRE6.

I know that [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) is a solution, but this driver does not suport table-valued parameters. [Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/feature-requests/63/) is the discussion

Comment: No one should be running JRE 6 anymore.  JDK 8 or higher is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017

"The JDBC 4.0 API was introduced as part of the Sun Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 6.0 and Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 6.0. " which is unsupported by March 6, 2017. I've found something like that on oracle website: https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4.0-fr-oth-JSpec/
but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find old drivers in some Microsoft websites e.g. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2505 will allow you to download *Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0* which works with Java 6.

> Download the SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0, a Type 4 JDBC driver that provides database connectivity through the standard JDBC application program interfaces (APIs) available in Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 5 and 6.

It's a very old, not secure and no longer officially supported version, just like your Java. You really should update.

Comment: Oh that's bad this file is not unzipping.
Thanks for your help. I'll find another way using JTDS to use table-valued parameters 
Yeah but I agree wit you, but I cannot change the versions of java on the production servers It's up to the company I work for.

Comment: If you have to download the UNIX version and extract JARs. But frankly don't do it, it will only work with old databases (pre MSSQL 2012)

Comment: There have been more recent versions that support Java 6 though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I couldn't find 3.0 or 4.0 driver downloads anymore. Officially 4.1 for Java 7 is the oldest supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate a paid solution, my employer offers a Java 1.6+ compatible JDBC Driver for SQL Server: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/sql/jdbc/

From the help documentation (http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RUD/jdbc/pg_startedintroj.htm):

> ### Java Version Support
>
> To deploy the driver JAR, you must have the JDK (Java Development Kit) 1.6 or higher installed on your system.